# Windows language for non-unicode programs change leads to error finding font

Tags: windows, localization

I have a legacy C++ program I have to maintain. We runs on Windows 7. Recently I encountered a bug in a pdf generation section of the code.

I change Windows' `Language for non-unicode programs` to `Korean (Korea)`, restart, then run the app. In the pdf generation code, there's this line:

```
pdf_font = pdf.load_font(L"Malgun Gothic", L"unicode", L"");
```

(I have no idea what goes inside `pdf.load_font`)

`pdf_font` here is `-1`. If the `Language for non-unicode programs` is English, there's no problem and `pdf_font` contains a valid value.

It's as if setting `Language for non-unicode programs` to `Korean (Korea)` hides `Malgun Gothic` font which can be seen before.

I'm not sure if this is a Windows issue or library issue. Any pointers are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

A general tip, for legacy app that don’t support unicode you better run windows in the language it’s supposed to be unless you recode the app to be unicode friendly.

I told it as Iam french, and even new application can fail if windows is in english and the french language pack is installed, it need the french windows.